# Replace a substring following a space and followed by commas in Python

Tags: python, regex

I am creating a script that parses a csv file and, in an effort to remain as agnostic to formatting as possible, I am using regular expressions to replace specific substrings. I am looking to replace a line in a cell with the author's name, which can be any number of characters and will contain an email address. It is guaranteed that there will be a space before the substring and that it will be followed by either newline characters (multiple lines in a cell) or a comma (last item in a cell).

I am using...

```
line = re.sub(' \S+[^,]', " " + author, line)
```

...to try to replace everything between the space and a potential comma, but it is including the trailing commas in the line in the expression and replacing them with the author. I have previously tried...

```
line = re.sub(' \S+(?!,)', " " + author, line)
```

...because this sounds like a job for a negative lookahead but I still haven't been able to retain the trailing commas.

I am new to regular expressions so there is probably something simple that I am missing, but I haven't been able to get this to work.

Comment: Use the [`csv`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) module.

Comment: Would :' [^\s,]+(?=[,\n])' work?

Comment: @Someone if you make that an answer I will accept it. I figured that it was something stupid that I was missing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
/[^\s,]+(?=[,\n])/
```

Comment: It turns out that I was asking the wrong question, but this answered what I asked. Thanks!